# Finding partial matches

Tags: regex, find-occurrences

Say, I have lines like:

```
SOMETHING.AA.AA.DARKSIDE

BLaH.AA.AA.Blah
```

I want to find for each line $before = $1; $after  = $2; of the $middle = ”AA”
Such that for example for line 1 I get:

```
$before= “SOMETHING.”
$After = “.AA.DARKSIDE”
```

And also

```
$before= “SOMETHING.AA”
$After = “.DARKSIDE”
```

My code looks like this:

```
$middle = “AA”;  

foreach (@lines){

   $line = $_;   

   while ($line =~m/^(.+)$middle(.+)$/g){

      $before = $1;
      $after  = $2;
  }
}
```

Is there a simple way to change regex in my while?
PS: `$middle` will be a variable so i cannot hardcode it. 
Thank you for help.

Comment: can you give an example of what you want your output to look like?

Comment: Does it work now, and you are only asking if there is a better way?

Comment: Can you have something like `SOMETHING.AA.AA.AA.DARKSIDE` as well? If so, are you expecting 3 possible outputs?

Comment: If it helps, there will be maximum 2 occurances of (for example).AA. most of the time there will be SOMETHING.AA.DARKSIDE. The current regex will only find one case out of SOMETHING.AA.AA.DARKSIDE.

Comment: Later i need to construct an animal like:SOMETHING.AA.AA.DARKSIDE = SOMETHING.BB.AA.DARKSIDE+SOMETHING.CC.AA.DARKSIDE but also SOMETHING.AA.AA.DARKSIDE = SOMETHING.AA.BB.DARKSIDE+SOMETHING.AA.CC.DARKSIDE. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to use regexes for that?

```
($before, $after) = split(/$middle\.$middle/, $line);
```

And then use `$before` and `$after` each once without and once with `$middle` concatenated to the end and start of the string respectively.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vince, I will do it your way.  I was hoping to have a one line solution, but realised (by browsing other posts) that it is rather impossible.

Comment: Glad I could help. Would you mind accepting my answer then? :)